# R syntax parser for .Net (C#)

Tags: c#, r, r.net

is there a way to check the written R syntax in .Net? I mean for the case that the user type some R scripts in an editor and the system will tell him before execution that something is wrong in the codes. I have tried using R.Net but it evaluates the code only during the execution process (because it calls the R-Engine immediately).

Comment: You could check out the source for R Tools for Visual Studio: https://github.com/Microsoft/RTVS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use R.NET to either call `base::parse` and check for errors, or to use a package like `lintr` for this purpose. The latter one can not only check for syntax errors but also for violations of a given coding style.

These solutions will however be probably too slow for displaying the errors in real time (while the user types). I am not aware of an R parser which is written in .NET.